# c++ default constructor fails to initialize public variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have simple sample:

```
#include <iostream>

class parent {
public:
    int i;
};

class child : public parent {
public:
    int d;
};

int main() {
    child c;
    std::cout << c.d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[If you do not explicitly initialize a base class or member that has constructors by calling a constructor, the compiler automatically initializes the base class or member with a default constructor.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr388.htm)

but all ints in c (`int d;` and `int i;`) are not initialized.

[image]

What is wrong with it? Or I do not see something obvios?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563221/is-there-an-implicit-default-constructor-in-c
look at the first answer's section default constructors and the notes for PODs

Comment: Fundamental types don't have constructors. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5113385/1801919.

Comment: The link that you provide is also for a Linux compiler, not VS2010

Comment: @RobGoodwin which link? which you? :)

Comment: @Csq the one in the question, right below the code block

Comment: But, isn't a conceptual error say that the variable was not initialized instead of assigned? "Initialize" is once, "assignment" can be done many times. In my opinion the variable was initialized but not assigned... Microsoft should review this warning message =P

Comment: @LucasMarcondesPavelski I think technically the variable is initialized, but not zero-initialized.

Comment: @juanchopanza : Indeed, though pedantically the correct terms here are that the variables are _default-initialized_ but not _value-initialized_.

Comment: @ildjarn there-s a whole chain of *initializeds* for built-in types. *value-initialized* means *zero-initialized* in this case, so I thought I would cut out the middle man.

Comment: @juanchopanza : Fair enough – as I said, I was being pedantic. :-]

Comment: As a side note, consider yourself lucky on two grounds.  First, some compilers will zero-initialise your builtins for you, and you'd have never known you are doing something wrong until when it actually hurts you the most.  Second, reading uninitialised values (your `cout` statement) is undefined behaviour which could have caused just about anything imaginable to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between default and zero initialization done on classes with no constructor and basic types:

```
child c1;           // Default initialized. int types are not initialized.
child c2 = child(); // Zero initialized.    int types are in initialized to zero.
// In C++ 11
child c3 {};        // Use new syntax for zero initialization
```

More detailed explanation:
   here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546745/14065
   here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280207/14065

Answer (score 4):

With built-in types, you actually have to do the initialization yourself:

```
class parent
{
 public:
  parent() : i() {}
  int i;
};
```

This will initialize `i` to `0`.

Comment: Is that standardized or VC++-only?

Comment: This is known as _value-initialization_.

Answer (score 4):

Built in data types (like `int`) are not really initialized. Their "default constructor" does nothing and they have no default value. Hence, they just get junk values. You have to explicitly initialize built in data types if you want them to have a specific value.

Comment: so for example for Enums and all other class simple data types (and complex) I would have to do what [juanchopanza](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14490503/1056328) suggests?

Comment: @myWallJSON: Yes. Except `std::complex` has a constructor that initializes its members to zero. If there isn't a constructor initializing something (or something explicitly being assigned to it), then it's going to have a junk value.