# C++: initialization of int variables by an implicit constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, int

I am learning C++ and I am a bit confused about the initialization of int variables.

This code (including the comments) is a copy/paste from Nawaz's answer in this topic [Why does C++ require a user-provided default constructor to default-construct a const object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a)

```
struct POD
{
  int i;
};

POD p1; //uninitialized - but don't worry we can assign some value later on!
p1.i = 10; //assign some value later on!

POD p2 = POD(); //initialized
```

For p2, I understand that the following is happening:

- The default constructor POD() is called to create a temporary POD object. The constructor is not user-defined, so it is implicit. For built-in types like int, the implicit default constructor does nothing (no initialization). Therefore *i* contains some random stuff.
- The copy constructor is called to create p2 using the temporary POD object (whose *i* is still uninitialized). Therefore the i member of p2 should not be initialized either.

However, the comment says that p2 is initialized!
Any explanation is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8280207/263895 points to the relevant section in the standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> For built-in types like int, the implicit default constructor does nothing (no initialization).

This is true but it is also not. Default initialization results in an unitialized object, while value initialization doesn't.

#### Why are these cases different?

#### 1. C++11, 8.5/11

> If **no initializer** is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has **indeterminate value**.

If you use `int i;` this results in an uninitialized integer!

#### 2. C++11, 8.5/10

> **An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized**.

If you use `int i = int();` you have a value-initialized `i`. Now, what is value-initialized?

#### 3. C++11, 8.5/7

> To **value-initialize** an object of type T **means**:
>
> - [...] (some options where T may be class or array type)
> - otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized.**

Ok now we know that `int i = int();` means having `i=0`.

**Since your struct is POD, value-initializing it means value-initializing all of its members.**

You can have a shortcut on the general behaviour

```
int i1, i2 = int();
std::cout << i1 << std::endl;
std::cout << i2 << std::endl;
```

If the memory where i1 resides, isn't zero by any luck you can have the output will probably be

```
somevalue
0
```

[*As @jogojapan mentioned correctly: Reading from `i1` is undefined in first place, so don't do it. You'll most likely observe what I describe here but since the standard doesn't enforce compilers to behave this way `i1` may be zero, or brake the expected result in any other strange way.*]

**Be aware of the following:**

> Note: Since () is not permitted by the syntax for initializer,
>
> > X a();
>
> is not the declaration of a value-initialized object of class X, but the declaration of a function taking no argument and returning an X.

<sub>Emphasis on standard quotes are mine.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If class type `POD` has no user-defined constructor (as is the case in your example), then `POD()` *does not call default constructor*. Instead the object is created without using any constructors at all. The compiler performs so called *value-initialization* of the temporary object. Value-initialization is a self-sufficient method of initialization, which does not necessarily use constructors. Instead, value-initialization of the entire object recursively performs value-initialization of all of its subobjects, one after another. For members of type `int` value-initialization means zero-initialization.

This is why `POD().i` is guaranteed to be zero. That zero was not placed there by any constructors. That zero was placed there by value-initialization.