# What does A a() mean?

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A():age(12){}
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    A a();
    cout << a.age << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using g++, I get an error:

> you can not see the member age, because a is not a class A()

Can someone explain this to me? What is `A a()`?

Comment: I rather think that's not the error g++ gives you...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line

```
A a();
```

declares a function named `a`, returning `A` with no arguments. (See [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)).

What you want is

```
A a = A(); // value-initialization
A a{}; // the same but only valid in C++11 (and currently not supported by MSVS)
```

or

```
A a; // default initialization
```

#### C++11, §8.5/10

> Note: Since () is not permitted by the syntax for initializer,
>
> > X a();
>
> is not the declaration of a value-initialized object of class X, but the declaration of a function taking no argument and returning an X.

For your class, value-initialization == default-initialization (at least for the outcome). 
See my answer here: [C++: initialization of int variables by an implicit constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690095/c-initialization-of-int-variables-by-an-implicit-constructor/17690411#17690411) for Infos on value- vs. default-initialization for POD or built-in types.

Comment: Er, why not just `A a;`?

Comment: Because newbies often try to initialize a new object on stack using the aboving syntax, `A a();`, wishing to call the default constructor. This, unfortunately, makes confusion.

Comment: @GManNickG : Thanks. In this case `A a;` is the same as `A a(A());` but if A is a POD the first means non-initialized members, the second means zero-initialized members. I just added how to value-initialize. But in this case, default initialization has at least the same result (prbably at a lower cost).

Comment: `void who_would_ever_use_this() { void syntax(); } void syntax() {}`

Comment: Why did nobody complain about my second example still being a most vexing parse? Anyway... removed :)

Comment: @GManNickG somtimes you want value initialization. The C++11 way is `A a{};`.

Answer (score 5):

It defines a function called `a` that returns an object of type `A`. This is known as the "most vexing parse".

Comment: +1 for formal jargon that's soooo true.

Comment: This is not the most vexing parse. It's just vexing. the MVP is `A x(A());`.