# c++ constructor and operator problem

Tags: c++, operators, constructor

I have a problem with constructor and assignment operator. This is my code:

```
class Class
{
    private:
        double number1;
        double number2;
    public:
        Class(double, double);
        Class& operator=(const Class& n);
}

Class::Class(double n1 = 0.0, double n2 = 0.0)
{
    this->number1 = n1;
    this->number2 = n2;
}

Class& operator=(const Class& n)
{
     this->number1 = n.number1;
     this->number2 = n.number2;
     return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Class n1(2., 3.), n2(7., -1.), n3();

    n2 = n1; // no problem
    n3 = n1; // problem

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please enlight me, why is there a problem with the second assignment in the main?

Thank you very much

**edit:** The following error occurs:

```
[Error] assignment of function 'Complex cislo2()'
[Error] cannot convert 'Complex' to 'Complex()' in assignment
```

Comment: What kind of problem are you experiencing?  Compilation error?  Run-time error?  Can you include the error in your question?

Comment: I added the error to the original post

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does A a() mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713124/what-does-a-a-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[amon's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/289419/c-constructor-and-operator-problem#comment598589_289419) is correct.

To explain it simply, in the sample code you provided:

```
Class n3();
```

Defines a *function* that takes no arguments, and returns an instance of `Class` by value.

It is a quirk in the C++ syntax.

To workaround this error, omit the empty parenthesis pair when initializing variables that does not take any constructor parameters.

Comment: You can also get in the habit of using braces to call the constructor in >= C++11. SomeType t{};