# Why parenthesis after an object variable declaration cause error (C++)?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I created a class which basically serves as a public structure in this example, and let's say the class name is `X`. I want to declare a local object in main function. The short version of my question is: I know we can do `X foo;`, but I think `X foo();` (attach a pair of parenthesis) should work, and I thought the first usage is actually a shorthand of the second usage. The entire code is provided below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X {
    public:
        int val1;
        int val2;
};

int main() {
    X a;
    X b();    // A warning here
    X *c = new X;
    X *d = new X();

    cout << "val of a: " << a.val1 << " " << a.val2 << endl;
    cout << "val of b: " << b.val1 << " " << b.val2 << endl;    // Compile error
    cout << "val of c: " << c->val1 << " " << c->val2 << endl;
    cout << "val of d: " << d->val1 << " " << d->val2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler complains:

```
11_stack.cpp:16:6: warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
        X ab();
            ^~
11_stack.cpp:16:6: note: replace parentheses with an initializer to declare a variable
        X ab();
            ^~
            {}
11_stack.cpp:22:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'
        cout << "val of b: " << b.val1 << " " << b.val2 << endl;
                                ^
11_stack.cpp:22:43: error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'
        cout << "val of b: " << b.val1 << " " << b.val2 << endl;
                                                 ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

My initial guesses are the following:

1. In any case, we shouldn't put an empty parenthesis after a declared variable.
2. It triggers `operator()`.

But later on I disproved both hypotheses. We can see the first disproof in the code: both `X *c = new X;` and `X *d = new X();` work. For the second one, I put additional code like this:

```
a();
```

Then I got compilation error messages:

```
11_stack.cpp:26:2: error: type 'X' does not provide a call operator
        a();
        ^
```

So what exactly cause the error?

Working environment:

- Mac OS 10.11.3
- g++ with flag c++11
- Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)

P.S. Please also help me think a better and descriptive post title if it's too ambiguous...

Comment: Actually reading the warning would have helped.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713124/what-does-a-a-mean/17713134?s=14|0.6182#17713134

Comment: See [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse); it's why C++11 introduced [uniform initialization syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization).

Answer (score 0):

`c` and `d` are pointers, so you need `c->val1` instead of using `.`.

Comment: This isn't even the OP's problem, although it _will_ be once OP solves the other problem

Comment: Thanks, I meant -> I've corrected accordingly