# C++ struct default constructor behavior

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

As I know, if the programmer doesn't implement any constructor, the compiler automatically generates default constructor that does nothing.
I think it works for struct as well.

I used this with inheritance.

```
struct Parent {
    int a;
};

struct Child : Parent {
    int b;
    Child () {
        printf("child constructor\n");
    }
}

int main () {
    Child c;
    printf("%d\n", c.a);        // c.a = dummy value
    printf("%d\n", c.b);        // c.b = 0
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, *c.a* was dummy value. However, when I change the Child constructor, it was zero.
The only difference is that the Child explicitly calls parent's constructor in its constructor.

```
struct Parent {
    int a;
};

struct Child : Parent {
    int b;
    Child () : Parent () {
        printf("child constructor\n");
    }
}

int main () {
    Child c;
    printf("%d\n", c.a);        // c.a = 0
    printf("%d\n", c.b);        // c.b = 0
    return 0;
}
```

What happens?
I spend some time but cannot find any reason.
The compiler I used is VS2008.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question seems to be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280023/does-a-c-struct-have-a-default-constructor

Answer (score 9):

`Parent` is a *POD*-type (plain old data type). It has no constructors or destructors (besides the implicit, which are trivial), complex members, etc. Its just a struct with scalars or other POD-type members. When you do this:

```
struct Child : Parent 
{
    int b;
    Child () {
        printf("child constructor\n");
    }
}
```

you're simply constructing the child object. No relevant construction of `Parent` is taking place. The base type undergoes *default initialization*:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p11**
>
> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is **default-initialized**; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2.

For your POD-type, this means:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p6**
>
> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.

But when you do *this*:

```
struct Child : Parent 
{
    int b;
    Child () : Parent () {
        printf("child constructor\n");
    }
}
```

something different happens: You're invoking *value-initialization* of the `Parent` base type. due to the **`()`**.

> **C++11 § 8.5,p10**
>
> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., **()**, shall be **value-initialized**.

For POD-types (of which `Parent` is one) value-initialization will eventually *zero-initialize* the members.

> **C++11 § 8.5,p7**
>
> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type *without a user-provided constructor*, then the object is **zero-initialized** and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Thus `a` is zero in the second case, but not in the first. (well, it *could* be zero in the first, you can't really say; its value is *indeterminate* until you assign *something* to it).

Comment: PODs have constructors, too.

Comment: @phresnel if you're referring to the implicit trivial constructors, they're noted; otherwise kindly elaborate.

Comment: @phresnel its a tricky part of the standard, so I'm never surprised when I get something wrong (likely did here too, wouldn't be surprised), so if I seemed a little anxious in that retort it wasn't intentional. Thanks for keeping me honest =P

Comment: But I did nothing except falsely accusing you of something :D

Comment: @phresnel no, actually, i look at that phrasing now and it isn't exactly crystal clear, it could imply only the destructors are trivial. I'll address it. No worries. Edit: much better. thanks.

Comment: We.. we.. welcome, I guess (but I know such situations, too :D)

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ STandard

> 11 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
>   (), shall be value-initialized.

and

> 8 To value-initialize an object of type T means: — if T is a (possibly
>   cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default
>   constructor, then the object is zero-initialized

So in code snippet

```
struct Parent {
    int a;
};

struct Child : Parent {
    int b;
    Child () : Parent () {
        printf("child constructor\n");
    }
```

class Parent is zero initialized. Its members of scalar types that is data member a is zero initialized.
}