# Will an unordered map create a zero initialized struct?

Tags: c++, struct, unordered-map

I have an unordered map that has a key of an `int` and a value of a `struct`. If the key is not found, I want the map to create a zero initialized `struct`.

```
struct TestStruct
{ 
   int a;
};

void foo()
{
   std::unordered_map<int, TestStruct> map;
   TestStruct& test = map[1];    
}
```

When debugging I can see that the values of `test.a == 0` but is this a coincidence?

Relevant post: [Does a c++ struct have a default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280023/does-a-c-struct-have-a-default-constructor)

Comment: No, this is not a coincidence. This is zero-initialization.

Comment: To be clear. The answer to the  question in the title is 'yes'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not coincidence, and yes, the map creates a zero-initialized struct. But let's go through the details:

New elements in the map are created with *value-initialization*; essentially with something like `::new (address) T()`. Value-initialization of a class without user-defined default constructor such as your `TestStruct` means that the object is zero-intialized, hence all non-static members are zero-initialized.

From [[dcl.init]p8](https://wg21.link/dcl.init#8):

> To *value-initialize* an object of type T means: [...] if `T` is a [...] class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized [...]

From [[dcl.init]p6](https://wg21.link/dcl.init#6):

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type T means: [...]  if `T` is a [...] class type, its padding bits (6.7) are initialized to zero bits
>   and each non-static data member, each non-virtual base class subobject, and, if the object is not a base
>   class subobject, each virtual base class subobject is zero-initialized [...]

But if your class had a user-defined default constructor, then value-initialization would result in that constructor being called. So it's true that your `int` is zero-intitialized, but only because of the particularly simple kind of class you have.