# when trying to insert the data into a vector for data type structure its returning wrong size

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to insert data into a vector which has the data type as structure. But when i am doing that its returning me a size one greater than what it should be.

```
struct data{
    int cID;
    int arrival;
    int service;
};

vector<data> myvect;

int main()
{
    data d1;

    myvect.push_back(data());

    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
        int i1 = i + 1;
        int i2 = i + 2;
        int i3 = i + 3;

        i1 >> d1.cID;
        i2 >> d1.arrival;
        i3 >> d1.service;

        myvect.push_back(d1);
    }
   cout << myvect.size();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `greater than what it should be` What should it be according to you? According to me, it should be `4`.

Comment: You push empty `data` to the vector, and then push 3 other `data` in the loop. The total is 4.

Comment: your whole code is equivalent to `vector<data> myvect(4);`. Are you intending to assign some numbers to the members of `d1`? Possibly from some iostream?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the bit shifting statements (e.g. `i1 >> d1.cID;`) that have no effect, the code is fine and inserts a total of four items to the vector.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Members of struct are not initialized in this case (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280023/does-a-c-struct-have-a-default-constructor ) , and bitshift operators yield ub, when right operand > number of bits in type of left operand. And as values of members of d1 are not determined, the chances are at least one othe them is > then number of bits in int, and so code triggers ub.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing a default initialised item into the vector before the loop.