# std::vector of struct: what will be the initial values of the members of the struct after a vector resize?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, standards, default-constructor

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct {
   unsigned short a;
   unsigned short b;
   unsigned long  c;
}T;

int main(int,char**)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    v.resize(256);
    std::cout << "a=" << v[0].a << " b=" << v[0].b << " c=" << v[0].c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

What will be `v[0].a` (and `b` and `c`)?

I am starting looking at the draft [N4659 Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) searching for `vector::resize`:

> **26.3.11.3 vector capacity [vector.capacity]** (at clause 13)
>
> `void resize(size_type sz);`
>
> *Effects*: If `sz < size()`, erases the last
>   `size() - sz` elements from the sequence. Otherwise, appends `sz - size()`
>   default-inserted elements to the sequence.

from there I need to know what *default-inserted* means and I arrive at:

> **26.2.1 General container requirements [container.requirements.general]** (at clause 15.2)
>
> — An element of `X` is *default-inserted* if it is initialized by
>   evaluation of the expression
>
> `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)`
>
> where `p` is the address of the uninitialized storage for the element
>   allocated within `X`.

Now, I need to know what happen inside `construct`, I found this note

> **26.2.1 General container requirements [container.requirements.general]** (at the end of clause 15)
>
> [ *Note*: A container calls `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args)`
>   to construct an element at `p` using `args`, with `m == get_allocator()`.
>   The default construct in allocator will call `::new((void*)p) T(args)`,
>   but specialized allocators may choose a different definition. — *end
>   note* ]

Am I fine? Does my snippet use a *specialized allocators*? I think that at the end my snippet will call `new T()` and now, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280207 I think `a`, `b` and `c`, will be `0`, am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)
```

is defined in [[allocator.traits.members]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.traits#members-5) it it states it does

> Effects: Calls `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` if that call is well-formed; otherwise, invokes `::new (static_­cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

Since `std::vector<T> v;` use the default allocator `std::allocator`, and `std::allocator` lacks a `construct` member, you fall back to the placement new initialization and if you expand it out you'll have

```
::new (static_­cast<void*>(p)) T();
```

and if we look up what `T()` does we get from [[dcl.init]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#11) that

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

and [[dcl.init]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#8) states that value initialization will

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

So all of the members of each newly created object will be zero initialized which means in this case they will all have the value of `0` since they are built in types.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're correct. You didn't use a specialized (customized) allocator. At last the elememts get [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). From [DefaultInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable):

> By default, this will call placement-new, as by `::new((void*)p) T()` (that is, value-initialize the object pointed to by `p`).

And as the result of [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), all the members of `T` will be zero-initialized.

(emphasis mine)

> if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), **the object is zero-initialized** and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;

Answer (score 3):

> Am I fine? Does my snippet use a specialized allocators?

Yes you are, no the allocator is not specialized. The default allocator used by `std::vector<T>` is `std::allocator<T>`. Currently `std::allocator<T>` is [still specified to have a `construct` member](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/depr.default.allocator) which does the same thing. But that is a deprecated member. Regardless, even if it's removed in the future entirely, the call via `std::allocator_traits` is still going to behave the same.

> [**[allocator.traits.members]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/allocator.traits.members)
>
> ```
> template <class T, class... Args>
>   static void construct(Alloc& a, T* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Calls `a.construct(p, std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)` if that call is well-formed; otherwise, invokes `​::​new(static_­cast<void*>(p)) T(std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)`.

As for what `new T()` does, you are 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I fine?

Yes.

> Does my snippet use a specialized allocators?

No. You use the default allocator which is `std::allocator`.

> I think that at the end my snippet will call new T() and now, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280207 I think a, b and c, will be 0, am I correct?

Correct.